# jQuery - Prevent Ajax POST from happening more than once every 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have implemented a wizard in html that shows a series of panels.  There is a Next button to navigate to the subsequent panel and a Finish button.  When the next button is selected, I have a click handler that performs an ajax post of some data to save the form.  I also do that with the Finish button.

It is not uncommon for users to press the Next button 3-6 times quickly.  I'd prefer to not queue up several posts if no data has changed in the form.  My thinking is that I'd only perform the post once every 10 seconds.  Is there a way to tell jQuery to do this?

Comment: Set a variable to keep track of the time when it was clicked, then inside of your function which calls the ajax, check to see if the last click was less than 10 seconds ago.

Comment: When you click next, it shows the next panel after successful ajax right? simply disable the form inputs and next button until you show the next panel. that would make it clear to the user that something is happening. If the user is clicking next multiple times, that's a sign that the user doesn't know something is happening or thinks it's broken.

Comment: No - the next panel will be shown and the Ajax request is scheduled asynchronously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your own wrapper around jQuery ajax call like this:

```
var lastPostCall = 0;

function ajaxWrapper(url, data, ...) {
   if(Date.now()-lastPostCall > 10000) {
      lastPostCall = Date.now();
      // Do the real ajax call
   }
}
```